Is the confusion matrix meaning the same within deep learning than within hypothesis testing?
Is the confusion matrix meaning the same within deep learning than within hypothesis testing?
I've read what the matrix is, and how to get the values. But in the case of deep learning for classification, for example,
we know the true values (as assigned by a human at least.)
And I am unsure whether there is any hypothesis in this case.
On the other hand, when doing hypothesis testing most of the times you wouldn't know the real answers, and the way the problems are framed seem in my mind completely different.
Does the confusion matrix have a different interpretation in these cases?
